# 25% off store-wide + free shipping on all orders

Tags: shipping, discount, price-rules

I would like to allow customers to purchase any item/s online and receive 25% off the subtotal + free shipping on their order.

Comment: Can you provide a little detail on your Magento version and shopping cart price rule? Also make sure your free shipping method is selected in System -> Configuration -> Shipping Methods

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question such that you want to give 25% on everything and free shipping for everybody.

Then you can do the following:

Create a shopping cart rule with **no conditions** and this action:

[image]

- Apply: Persent of product price discount
- Discount Amount: 25
- Free Shipping: For shipment with matching items